# PHP+Composer: Adding files to autload_static.php to load package

Tags: php, composer-php

I had problems loading package I have required via composer
`composer require package`

PHP (`version 5.6`) said it did not recognised this package.

When looking into the scripts, I found in `autoload_real.php` these lines:

```
$useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION');
if ($useStaticLoader) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

    call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitb5ab90658915f56241dbbea020198264::getInitializer($loader));
} else {
    $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
    foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
        $loader->set($namespace, $path);
    }

    $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($map);
    foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
        $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
    }

    $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
    if ($classMap) {
        $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
    }
}
```

My packages are listed inside the `autoload_psr4.php` file and are returned in the packages array but the code is going in to the if clause ($useStaticLoader is true) and in the `autoload_static.php` my package is not listed.

When setting `$useStaticLoader` to false, the else clause is loading my package as expected.

I'll add that the package I'm installing declare itself as a `psr4` package.

What is the static flag mean and how can I make my package be listed in the `autoload_static.php` array?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Do you install local or remote package? Could you show us its composer.sjon?

Comment: I have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

**[Allow optionally disabling the static autoloader](https://github.com/legoktm/composer/commit/24afcee671dd7ba61bfdf2bc26bc02618cbbce7c)**

> The static autoloader presents a problem for environments where
>   pre-PHP
>   5.6 syntax compatibility is required. Many projects have automated CI that runs a linter across all files in the repository to prevent
>   developers from accidentally introdcing incompatible syntax. And while
>   the static autoloader properly guards itself on lower PHP versions, it
>   will still trip up linters. Given the number of bugs filed about this,
>   it appears to be a common setup: [#5255](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5255), [#5316](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5316), [#5324](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5324), and [#5407](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5407).
>
> This adds a --no-static option to the dump-autoload command, which
>   will disable the static autoloader by updating autoload_real.php to
>   not look for the file, and removes autoload_static.php if it exists.

Also you can avoid this using `--optimize-autoloader` flag with [install / update](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install).

**P.S.:** I had the same problems with php 5.6 too, check your path and namespaces twice!